# Xamarin NuGet package constraints do not appear to be working

Tags: nuget, xamarin-studio

Xamarin Studio 5.5 added support for package version constraints in the packages.config file according to the [release notes](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_5.5/xamarin.studio_5.5/). Following their example:

```
<package id="jQuery" version="1.4.1" targetframework="net40" allowedversions="[1.4.1,1.8)"></package>
```

... I changed my packages.config to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  ...
  <package id="ServiceStack" version="3.9.71" allowedversions="[3.9.71,4)" targetFramework="net45"></package>
  <package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="3.9.71" allowedversions="[3.9.71,4)" targetFramework="net45"></package>
  <package id="ServiceStack.Logging.NLog" version="3.9.71" allowedversions="[3.9.71,4)" targetFramework="net45"></package>
  <package id="ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql" version="3.9.71" allowedversions="[3.9.71,4)" targetFramework="net45"></package>
  <package id="ServiceStack.Redis" version="3.9.71" allowedversions="[3.9.71,4)" targetFramework="net45"></package>
  <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="3.9.71" allowedversions="[3.9.71,4)" targetFramework="net45"></package>
</packages>
```

(ServiceStack v3 is available under the BSD license, while v4 is commercial.)

Unfortunately, Xamarin Studio is still telling me I have 6 updates available and tries to update them all to version 4.0.32 if I allow it to try to update.

Has anyone gotten this to work successfully in Xamarin Studio 5.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the release notes have reformatted the original markup so the xml being displayed is incorrect. The attribute allowedVersions is case sensitive. You have it all in lower case.

Your packages.config file should look something like:

```
<packages>
  <package id="ServiceStack" version="3.9.71" allowedVersions="[3.9.71,4)" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="3.9.11" allowedVersions="[3.9.71,4)" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Logging.NLog" version="3.9.71" allowedVersions="[3.9.71,4)" targetFramework="net45"/>
  <package id="ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer" version="3.9.14" allowedVersions="[3.9.71,4)" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Redis" version="3.9.11" allowedVersions="[3.9.71,4)" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="4.0.32" allowedVersions="[3.9.71,4)" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Thanks @matt-ward. Contrary to the downvotes and the vote to close, I knew you would quickly be able to spot what I was doing wrong. And I see that the code snippet in the release notes has already been taken down until it can be corrected. Kudos for that as well.

Comment: I am trying to correct the xml in the release notes which is why it is currently missing. I broke it on the docs site :)

Comment: OK it is fixed now. Had to resort to plain old html to get the XML to be displayed.